# Check if a string contains at least 10 digits, 12 uppercase letter and 20 lowercase letter

Tags: regex, string

What could be the regular expression to have at least 10 digits, 12 uppercase letter and 10 lowercase letters?

The string can start with any of the above and could be randomly 
placed. For example, `AB12jgGGfWisLWfoi34R32SgD42DSf3453jfh`.

I used `(?=.*\\d.*\\d)(?![.\\n])(?=.*[A-Z].*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z].*[a-z]).*$` This is what I used for at least two uppercase, two lowercase and two digits. But adding 10 redundant `\\d`'s in the expression above doesn't seem a good practice.

Moreoever, using `\\d{10}` doesn't work as if we expect consecutive 10 digits.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean

Comment: I hope that this isn't going to be a password "strength" check & rule :-)

Comment: Spiting this check into 3 separate steps would a hell of a lot easier (and more maintainable). Step 1: Check if the string contains at least 10 digits. Steps 2 & 3 should be obvious. Regular expressions work great for simple things, but there comes a point where they just make the solution harder.

Comment: @captain : I was actually trying to create password filter with the above reg ex..isn't that an appropriate way to do?

Comment: @230490 : It is appropriate to create a password filter using regex... Whether it is appropriate for that password to need "at least 10 digits, 12 uppercase letter and 20 lowercase letter" is another question!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^(?=(.*?\d){10})(?=(.*?[A-Z]){12})(?=(.*?[a-z]){10})[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bT3nB2/1)

Or even better performing regex:

```
^(?=(?:\D*\d){10})(?=(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){12})(?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){10})[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

This is because negation pattern works better than lazy quantifier `.*?` (thanks to @nhahtdh).

Comment: Ok here we go again. It is actually exact opposite, `.*` will slow down this regex as opposed to `.*?`. If you open above demo link and click on `regex debugger`, you will see **FINISHED in 169 STEPS**. Now change the regex to all `.*` in place of `.*?` and then click on same menu option. It will now show **FINISHED in 65450 STEPS** Don't know how reliable this regex101's debugging info is but that is huge difference.

Comment: Yeah it seems so.A lot of backtracking is involved in case of `.*`.I guess `.*` is slower but m not sure as the number of steps is always dubious.

Comment: ok here is more authoritative confirmation of what I was saying. [Check this  performance test demo of both versions of same regex](http://jsperf.com/test-greedy-regex) Click on **Run again** button and you will see huge performance slowdown in using `.*` against `.*?`

Comment: Yeah thanx for that.I forgot to update.I checked the performance at regexhero.net and found d same.`.*` is slower . :)

Comment: On the same topic, you might want to explicitly specify the `.*?` with the negated character class: https://regex101.com/r/bT3nB2/2 (failing case, 34 steps) compared with https://regex101.com/r/gJ1bG5/1 (failing case, 4k steps)

Comment: Yes completely agree, negation always works better than lazy quantifier. I will edit to clarify.

Comment: (?=(.*\d){10})(?=(.*[A-Z]){12})(?=(.*[a-z]){10}).*$

Wont this work?

Comment: There is some discussion here on using .* vs `.*?`