# Switching between http and https page on single website

Tags: apache, .htaccess

We are running a web-site with both HTTP and HTTPs protocols. We need a rule for .htaccess file where we can handle these requests i.e. non-https page should redirect with http:// and https page should redirect with https:// protocol. 
We are using apache. Any help would greatly appreciate.

Comment: Please provide some details on what the redirection rules should be like. Ps: I'm not the downvoter.

Comment: Thanks Ravi, I am using both protocols on my website. For example Let's take two pages, Home page which is not using ssl and contact page which is using ssl. So if someone tries to reach home page using https://homepage.com then he must redirected to http://homepage.com. Reverse case with contact page which is using ssl.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your .htaccess file at your site's root directory.

```
RewriteEngine on

# Force http://
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/|/dl/memorandum.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,L]

# Force SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/contact$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

---

You can match on multiple pages by using the `|` OR operator.

```
^/(contact|profile|transactions)$ [NC]
```

If the URLs are long you can drop the `$` and do a prefix match as

```
^/(contact|profile|transactions) [NC]
```

This will match on `/contact-page` or `/contact/page` as well now.

---

Use negation to force HTTP on all the rules that do not require SSL.

```
RewriteEngine on

# Force http://
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(contact|login|cart|register|forgot-your-password|request)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Force SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(contact|login|cart|register|forgot-your-password|request)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: how can I add multiple urls in this line "
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/contact$"

Comment: Seem to work but with an error.
See this link: https://www.netlawman.co.in/dl/memorandum-and-articles-of-association this is non-https page but still open with https:// which is supposed to redirect to http://

Comment: What's the actual rule you've added to your htaccess?

Comment: This one:
# Force http://
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,L]

# Force SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(contact|login|cart|register|forgot-your-password|request)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

Comment: You have to modify this `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$` as well to match links you want to force `http` on. For e.g. for the link you've shared, I'll include it as shown in my update.

Comment: These are hundred or may be thousands of links and we can't put each in this condition.

Comment: You're out of luck then because the server can't guess whether a particular URL should be served on http or SSL on its own. It will always be served with the protocol specified by the client unless a rule explicitly overrides it.

Comment: Hold on a second. I got an idea.

Comment: Please, check my update. By negating the SSL's request uri rule with `!` you can force http on all the links that do not require SSL. I think this should work for you.

Comment: Thanks, @anubhava. Hey, do you have any favorite resource which explains regex from performance point of view? I'm interested in when should one make use of lazy, greedy, and possessives i.e how to avoid unnecessary backtracking etc.

Comment: Actually I just did this exercise yesterday: [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28428252/548225)